# Lua 5.1 workaround for __gc metamethod for tables

Tags: lua, garbage-collection, lua-table, lua-5.1

I'm currently facing the problem that you can't use the `__gc` method for tables in Lua 5.1, as they are implemented in Lua 5.2. However, I want to release allocated native resources once the lua table gets collected. Is it possible to make a workaround which gives me the functionality of `__gc` metamethod in Lua 5.2 for Lua 5.1?

Comment: Use a proxy object in the table and put the `__gc` metamethod on it. When the table gets collected the proxy will then get collected and your `__gc` method will be called. Though this may require extra gc cycles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In lua 5.1 the only lua values that work with `__gc` metamethod is `userdata`. Naturally any hack or workaround will have to involve `userdata` in someway. Normally there is no way to just create newuserdata from the lua side but there is one "*hidden*" undocumented function `newproxy` for doing just that.

`newproxy` takes an optional bool or userdata parameter. If you pass in `true` then you get a userdata with a new metatable attached. If you pass in another `userdata` then the new userdata will be assigned the same metatable as the one passed in.

So now you can just hack together a function that'll make `__gc` work on tables:

```
function setmt__gc(t, mt)
  local prox = newproxy(true)
  getmetatable(prox).__gc = function() mt.__gc(t) end
  t[prox] = true
  return setmetatable(t, mt)
end
```

And a quick test to confirm the behavior:

```
iscollected = false
function gctest(self)
  iscollected = true
  print("cleaning up:", self)
end

test = setmt__gc({}, {__gc = gctest})
collectgarbage()
assert(not iscollected)

test = nil
collectgarbage()
assert(iscollected)
```

[**IDEOne Demo**](http://ideone.com/tnB53x)

Note that lua 5.2+ and later no longer have `newproxy` since `__gc` is officially supported on tables.

Comment: There is one thing to concern while using suggested solution - if you will traverse the table by pairs() you will get one addition key. It  is possibly to avoid it by using proxy object with proper metamethods in place of original table.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

## `__gc` support in `setmetatable` for Lua 5.1

The following code overwrites `setmetatable` to make it to work with `__gc` metamethod, not attaching anything to the original table.
It will make `__gc` work exactly as Lua 5.2+, as you will see in the following examples.

```lua
-- Support to __gc metamethod
do
  local gcProxies = { }

  -- The values in gcProxies are strong because they refer to their own keys.
  -- So, it needs to be forced to have also weak values, since we want to remove each entry from gcProxies if its key (metatable) is not in use anymore anywhere.
  setmetatable(gcProxies, { __mode = 'kv' }) -- Make keys and values weak

  local _setmetatable = setmetatable
  function setmetatable(table, metatable)
    if metatable.__gc then
      -- Create an empty userdata (the only values in Lua 5.1 that work with __gc metamethod is userdata).
      -- Then, we insert it in gcProxies (weak table); so when metatable is not in use anymore, it will also remove it from gcProxies.
      gcProxies[metatable] = newproxy(true)

      -- __gc from metatable of gcProxies[metatable] call __gc from metatable
      getmetatable(gcProxies[metatable]).__gc = function()
        if type(metatable.__gc) == 'function' then
          metatable.__gc(table)
        end
      end
    end

    return _setmetatable(table, metatable)
  end
end
```

Example 1:

```lua
  local o = { x = 'hi' }
  setmetatable(o, { __gc = function(o) print(o.x) end })
  o = nil

  collectgarbage() --> hi
```

Example 2:

```lua
  local o = { x = 'hi' }
  local mt = { __gc = true }

  setmetatable(o, mt)
  mt.__gc = function(o) print(o.x) end
  o = nil

  collectgarbage() --> hi
```

Example 3:

```lua
  local mt = { __gc = function(o) print(o[1]) end }
  local list = nil

  for i = 1, 3 do
    list = setmetatable({ i, link = list }, mt)
  end
  list = nil

  collectgarbage() --> 3; 2; 1
```

Example 4:

```lua
  local A = { x = 'This is A' }
  local B = { f = A }

  setmetatable(B, { __gc = function(o) print(o.f.x) end })
  A, B = nil

  collectgarbage() --> This is A
```

Example 5:

```lua
do
  local t = {
    __gc = function()
      -- Your 'atexit' code comes here
      print('Finishing Lua program')
    end
  }
  setmetatable(t, t)

  _G['*ATEXIT*'] = t
end

--> Finishing Lua program
```

Example 6:

```lua
do
  local mt = {
    __gc = function(o)
      -- Executes on collectgarbage
      print('New cycle')

      setmetatable({ }, getmetatable(o)) -- Creates new object for next cycle
    end
  }

  -- Creates first object
  setmetatable({ }, mt) --> New cycle
end

collectgarbage() --> New cycle
collectgarbage() --> New cycle
collectgarbage() --> New cycle
```